# Why am I unable to receive text messages with Twilio and Parse?

Tags: javascript, twilio

I'm trying to receive text messages sent to my Twilio number using [Parse](http://www.parse.com) and Parse's cloud code Twilio Module. I have followed the instructions [here](https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_modules_guide#twilio-inbound).

I set the SMS request URL for the Twilio number I want to receive text messages from to

https://myAppID:javascript-key=myJavaScriptKey@api.parse.com/1/functions/receiveSMS

and of course I used my parse app ID and my parse javascript key.

I then created the cloud function in Parse:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("receiveSMS", function(request, response) {
response.success("Received a new text: " + request.params.From);
});
```

and then I have a little webpage with some jquery calling that cloud function

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
alert('button');

Parse.Cloud.run('receiveSMS', {

    }, {
        // Success handler
        success: function(message) {
            alert('Success: ' + message);
        },
        // Error handler
        error: function(message) {
            alert('Error: ' + message);
        }
    }); 

});
```

I tried texting my Twilio number and then used my page with the code above to call the cloud code function "receiveSMS". The response is successful and I get the message "Received a new text:undefined". So it seems like I'm able to detect a new text message was sent but I'm getting undefined instead of the number the text message was from. I'd also like to get the message too. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Hey, I'm a Twilio developer evangelist. I'd like to help, but haven't really used Parse before myself. It does look like you're 95% there. What happens if you try to log out the whole `request.params` object? Could express be downcasing the parameter names from "From" to "from"?

Comment: Hi, well I'm not using the express option. I followed the directions where it said: "Alternatively, it is also possible to create a Cloud Function that will receive a request from Twilio. This does not require the use of the Twilio Cloud Module, since the endpoint is set on the Twilio website. Start by defining a new Cloud Function." The instructions can be found [here](https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_modules_guide#twilio). I did try changing From to from anyway and nothing happened.

Comment: I see, it's not Express. Did you manage to log out the entire `request.params` object at all? Having read the Cloud Function documentation, it appears that cloud functions expect the parameters being sent to them to be in JSON format, whereas Twilio delivers parameters as just normal POST parameters, as if from a form. So, althought it's against what the docs on the Twilio implementation say, I'm just worried that the parameters aren't getting through at all. Could you post a gist to the results of logging `request.params`?

Comment: From logs: I2014-08-21T15:56:55.901Z] v91: Ran cloud function receiveSMS with:
  Input: {}
  Result: {}
I2014-08-21T15:56:55.943Z] Received a new text: [object Object]

Comment: when using request.params.from
I2014-08-21T16:45:57.656Z] v95: Ran cloud function receiveSMS with:
  Input: {}
  Result: undefined
I2014-08-21T16:45:57.689Z] Received a new text: undefined

Comment: Actually I'm getting this I2014-08-21T18:05:03.339Z] v111: Ran cloud function receiveSMS with:
  Input: {"ToCountry":"US","ToState":"IN","Body":"fdfdfd","FromCountry":"US"}
  Result: Received a new text: +18185555555
Of course that is just as you said, the gist of what I'm getting. I get everything in the log. I just don't know how to access it.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I know what's happened now, thanks for getting me more details in the comments.

You are calling your `receiveSMS` function in two ways. Firstly, it gets called when you send an SMS to your Twilio number. When that request is received you do get all the parameters logged out and your log will show `"Received a new text: +YOUR_PHONE_NUMBER"`.

The problem is when you are calling your `receiveSMS` function from a web page. At that point, there are no parameters in the request and it is why you see `undefined` in the log. The `receiveSMS` function is for Twilio's benefit really, in that you are able to respond with [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) to tell Twilio to do about the message.

If you want to get back the details of SMS messages sent to your Twilio number, you can retrieve the data using our REST API in a different Cloud Function like so:

```
var client = require('twilio')('TWILIO_SID', 'TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN');

Parse.Cloud.define('fetchSMS', function(request, response) {
  client.messages.list({ to: YOUR_TWILIO_NUMBER }, function(err, data){
    numbers = data.messages.map(function(message){
      return message.from;
    }).join(', ');
    response.success("Received messages from: " + numbers);
  })
});
```

Then, if you change your webpage to call `Parse.Cloud.run('fetchSMS', { ... })` instead then your response should be a list of numbers you have received SMS messages from. Hopefully you can build on that.

Do let me know if this helps.